# Content Type not queryable in Content Search Web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, content-type, content-query-web-part, content-search-web-part

Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is to have a page with two Content Search Web Parts that each pull back items of a specific content type. To do this I have created a few custom content types on my site, however I only seem to be able to query/refine by one of content types and not by the other.

I can't think of anything I may have done differently when setting up the content types (they both have the same parent, same group and almost identical columns).

Can anyone weigh in on where I may be going wrong?

Edit: Using SharePoint Online

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible you haven't run a full crawl after the non-queryable content type has been created?

Comment: I've kicked off a new one by going to Site Settings -> Search and Offline Availability and hitting "Reindex site". I made this content type last week so I would have thought that SP would have picked it by now...

Comment: Can you post the query test you are using?

Comment: [Just using a basic query with a SPContentType refiner](http://imgur.com/a/rJCOQ) 
Expecting to see more than the single content type there.

Comment: Try switching to the Advanced mode in the Basic tab of the query editor dialog. For the query use ContentType:"Content Type Name Here". You could also assign the crawled property ows_ContentType to a managed property RefinableString** and re-use it for other scenarios

Comment: Tried that, not getting any results page. Might be worth noting that SPO doesn't actually seem to be indexing pages of that content type.

Comment: Hi Dev_jd, just following up on this one to see if you were able to make Content Types searchable, I'm also able to just filter through them using spcontenttype property but can't seem to find a crawled property that will let me search for this